# Why am I getting an Attribute error on a string object?

Tags: python

Depending on which classroom a pupil is in, I would like to return one of two values and assign it to the variable name 'scoreMutiplier' which would then be used later elsewhere in my code. However, I am still pretty new to this and have been confronted with the following error message after the first scenario when I execute my code: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isin'`

```
import numpy as np

pupil = 'Tom'

classroom_A = ['Peter', 'Greg', 'Susan', 'Tom', 'John']

classroom_B = ['Steve', 'Joe', 'Jose', 'Pam', 'Paul']

scenario = [((pupil.isin(classroom_A )) & (~pupil.isin(classroom_B ))),
            ((pupil.isin(classroom_B )) & (~pupil.isin(classroom_A )))]

result = [3,1]

scoreMultiplier = np.select(scenario , result, default='')

print(scoreMultiplier)
```

What is the best way to make this work?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the right idea, but are using the wrong function. A `str` object does not have an `isin()` function. You should use the keyword `in` which, in the case of a list, check if the list contains the given object (in other cases it calls the object's `__contains__()` function). You should also use Python's binary operators (`and`, `or`, `not`) when working with `boolean` instead of bitwise operators. So that would mean to change this part of the code to the following:

```py
scenario = [pupil in classroom_A and pupil not in classroom_B,
            pupil in classroom_B and pupil not in classroom_A]
```

Comment: Thanks thats seems to have done it. However, I got a warning message:- DeprecationWarning: select condlists containing integer ndarrays is deprecated and will be removed in the future. Use `.astype(bool)` to convert to bools. 
This actually prevented the use of the variable in a calculation further down in my code, which I got around by converting the variable to a float. 
But how should I change my code to comply with what the warning message is suggesting?

Comment: It's hard to answer this only through comments, I don't know which variable is this concerning. When I run the above code there is no warning message.

Comment: "....You should also use Python's binary operators (and, or, not) when working with boolean instead of bitwise operators...'  your explanation and the amendment @Samansi Hymavathi address the final problem that I was having perfectly. Ace!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Check this code:

```
import numpy as np

pupil = 'Tom'

classroom_A = ['Peter', 'Greg', 'Susan', 'Tom', 'John']

classroom_B = ['Steve', 'Joe', 'Jose', 'Pam', 'Paul']

scenario = [pupil in classroom_A and pupil not in classroom_B,
            pupil in classroom_B and pupil not in classroom_A]

result = [3,1]

scoreMultiplier = np.select(scenario , result, default='')

print(scoreMultiplier)
```